# Using variables and for loop with array in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have declared an array called arrUsers in my shell script. I am trying to get all the users who have logged onto a linux server using the last command. I want to do something like this:

```
declare -a arrUsers=()
for user in `last | awk '{print $1}'
do
    if $user not in arrUsers()
        do arrUsers += users
```

I am not quite sure what the correct syntax to do this is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you your aim is to "deduplicate" the output of `last`, the `awk` invocation you already have seems a more natural place than a shell loop. (And note that `last` (at least the one I have, from util-linux 2.37) also emits lines that don't start with a user name). Are you interested in how to keep the elements of an array unique while adding new ones, regardless of the specific example in your question?

Comment: Yes, I also would like to know how to do that

Comment: The answer I posted tries to address all the points in my previous comment, including how to avoid adding duplicate elements to an array - see the nested loops snippet in point 2.

Answer (score 2):

I see two distinct points here: getting a list of users that successfully logged in (1) and adding that list to a Bash array (2).

1. Parsing `last`'s output is not straightforward, because it also contains lines that do not start with a user name. A few alternatives you have on Linux:

   ```bsh
   lslogins -r | awk -F '[ ]' 'NR > 1 && $6 { print $2 }'
   ```

   `lslogins` displays information about users (not login events), hence it only outputs one line per user. The `-r` option tells it not to columnate the output, allowing us to assume a single space as a column separator and make use of `awk`'s ability to avoid squeezing space characters when `FS` is not a single space (the default). I am not sure, though, that no space characters will appear in the content of any of `lslogins`'s output fields.

   Alternatively:

   ```bsh
   utmpdump /var/log/wtmp 2>/dev/null |
     gawk -v FPAT='\\[[^][]*\\]' '
       $1 == "[7]" { gsub(/[][]/,"",$4); sub(/ +$/,"",$4); users[$4] }
       END { for (user in users) print user }'
   ```

   This uses a non-standard GNU AWK's feature to split records based on a regular expression (stored in `FPAT`) describing the fields' content. In `utmpdump`'s output, fields are wrapped in square brackets and separated by a single space. We filter records based on their type, stored in the first field (see `man 5 wtmp` for more on this).

   Note that, while creating such names would definitely not be an advisable choice, Linux allows user names not to conform to [the standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_437) and include characters not in the [portable filename character set](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_282) — including spaces. Space characters would not be an issue with `lslogins -r`, which escapes them (as `\x20`), but trailing spaces would not be unambiguously represented in `utmpdump`'s output and the above code snippet removes them.
2. You can place a list of unique user names in an array using:

   ```bsh
   readarray -t users \
     < <(lslogins -r | awk -F '[ ]' 'NR > 1 && $6 { print $2 }')
   ```

   Or, to add elements to an existing array, without resetting it:

   ```bsh
   readarray -t -O "${#users[@]}" users \
     < <(lslogins -r | awk -F '[ ]' 'NR > 1 && $6 { print $2 }')
   ```

   These do not take care of keeping elements unique, though. To achieve that, you will probably need a couple of loops:

   ```bsh
   while IFS= read -r user
   do
     for el in "${users[@]}"
     do
       if [ "$el" = "$user" ]
       then
         continue 2
       fi
     done
     users+=( "$user" )
   done < <(lslogins -r | awk -F '[ ]' 'NR > 1 && $6 { print $2 }')
   ```

   As an alternative (if your Bash version supports it), you may use an associative array and store user names as keys, ensuring each one will only appear once:

   ```bsh
   declare -A users
   while IFS= read -r user
   do
     users["$user"]=''
   done < <(lslogins -r | awk -F '[ ]' 'NR > 1 && $6 { print $2 }')
   ```

   You may then iterate over them with the `"${!array[@]}"` syntax:

   ```bsh
   for username in "${!users[@]}"
   do
     printf '%s\n' "$username"
   done
   ```